# Accessing pdf from network drive in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my view, I am trying to access a PDF and show it in a .
 The following works:

```
<div>
    <object width="1000" height="1000" type="application/pdf"
            data="2013001234_I_1234567897EIGHTRSO07.PDF" id="pdf_content"></object>
</div>
```

But the following does not:

```
 <div>
    <object width="1000" height="1000" type="application/pdf"
            data="\\10.1.2.3\f$\Sten\2013001234_I_1234567897EIGHTRSO07.PDF" id="pdf_content"></object>
</div>
```

So in otherwords, if it on the network, I cant get it to display. But it the file is local, it works fine.  What would I need to do to get the file to display the PDF?

Comment: How would a browser, which is running on a different machine than the server, access that url if it were presented in the html? The only way this could work is for an corporate intranet site where all users have access to these paths.

Comment: This is all within my company on the same network.  All the users authenticated by active directory do have read access to the directory.  But something is still stopping it.  I get an error: "Not allowed to load local resources" but I just pushed f12 to see this error.  Maybe I should just copy the file to a local area before displaying it? Since I am new to mvc I am trying to figure this out.  It is very different from winforms that I have been writing for years.

Comment: Test it outside of MVC. Create an HTML page with the above code hard coded and test it on a couple of PCs and see if it works.